# How to connect to an avaya ACD00-0049JP

Tags: telephone, avaya, call-manager

In the place were I work they have an outdated AVAYA device with model ACD00-0049JP. We´ve been tasked with changing certain configurations. The people who were in charge of these devices left years ago.

[image]

They did not leave any documentation or configuration parameters, all they gave us was an ID and a password,so we are blind here, and have no experience with any of these devices. They did have a manual but its for a software they don´t have anymore. We´ve been searching all over the place for information, manuals, diagrams, anything.

So, the last couple of days, we´ve been trying to connect to the device. We tried connecting via IP using IP OFFICE and AVAYA SITE ADMINISTRATION to no avail. When we scan the IPs of the network we can see an AVAYA device, so it is on the network, we even used an ethernet crossover cable to be connected as directly as possible.

We also tried connecting via serial cable, with the same results.

We will be thankful for any kind of information you could provide on how to establish this connection, we´ll try and figure out the rest once we are able to communicate with the device.

Comment: Which software did you use when you connected to the device by serial cable?

Comment: We used Site Administration

Comment: Try the old school windows software which is called HyperTerminal, you can download it from: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=53314

Comment: What open ports are there when you do a portscan on it?

Comment: When I ran the port scan there seemed to be no ports available on the AVAYA devices.

Comment: In the end we carefully replaced some of the network  and serial cables. After some trial and error we were able to connect using another serial cable connected to another port.  Maybe the port they used to connect was faulty. We also used site admin to connect using COM1 port.

Answer (score 2):

That unit is a an Automatic Call Distribution system, the robot that prompts you to enter a number when you call in, to route your call to a specific person. Here is the manual. [Manual](https://downloads.avaya.com/elmodocs2/comm_mgr/r3_1/03_300151_5/07_300478_1/07_300478_1.pdf)

I believe you will need to connect to the gateway to gain access to it. I have not worked on Avaya equipment in over 7 years but will try to help if you can review this doc and try to get a connection established.

The manual also includes a compatibility table that shows what hardware you need to connect to the version on your system. You may need to perform some packet captures and try a telnet or null modem connection to get some of that info if the system is that old.

Comment: You don't need a gateway.  This is the small end of the GS3 Defiinty hardware, generally for a small or branch office.  There's an RS232 service port on it.

Answer (score 1):

Without documentation this will be pretty hard. Have you tried asking Avaya for support?

Is that a PBX? You've identified a network port? Was it connected?

1. Find out the device's MAC address. Check the switch MAC table on the port it's connected to.
2. Find out the IP address that's used with the MAC. If a ping/ARP scan doesn't give a clue - it's possible that a static IP is set up that your network doesn't use - you'll need to tap into the switch port (set port mirroring to another port and capture the packets).
3. Check standard protocols on that IP (telnet, SSH, HTTP, HTTPS).
4. Run a port scan. Possibly the packet capture already gave some clues.
5. Try to telnet into the ports you've discovered as listeners.

Answer (score 0):

You have an [Avaya Definity Server CSI](http://downloads.avaya.com/css/P8/documents/100009027) platform, (that's the manual to the platform around the time the name was changed to "Avaya Communications Server", it's the small-office or branch-office version of the Definity PBX hardware).

Your actual model number is not very informative at all (it's essentially a generic chassis) - what's important are the what model cards ("circuit packs" or "media gateways") you have in it.

[This Avaya Product Matrix](http://downloads.avaya.com/css/P8/documents/003682961) circa 2002 should help you identify what software you might be running.

At any rate you're looking for documentation on the TN2402 processor board (common to Definity CSI), not your chassis model.

You should have a terminal port and two (three?) RS232 serial interfaces (all RJ45 interfaces, cisco cables will work).  One of these should give you a serial console (VT220, 19200 should work iirc).

You should have a 10baseT port as well - you can probably telnet or maybe ssh to that (the machine is probably running a few "noisy" daemons, like routed, so a tcpdump on that interface should reveal its IP.  No PBX will have a DHCP address.)  So the login you'll need is called "init" (you shouldn't need a password on one of the RS232 ports)...

[This administrator's guide to the communications manager](http://downloads.avaya.com/css/P8/documents/100010640) should give you an idea of basic configuration once you get logged in.

All of the docs are on https://support.avaya.com, it can be difficult to navigate through the product rebranding from AT&T -> Lucent -> Avaya and the often arbitary product name changes...